# Does a subset of a tag count as a synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

When suggesting tag synonyms, I understand similar words that means the same thing would be a suitable candidate. For example: [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [oracle-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-java).

However, I noticed quite a few synonyms suggestions where I feel one word is a subset to another.

For example would the following be considered synonyms:

- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
- [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)
- [java-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-classes) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)

I only ask as I have seen suggestions like this for other tags.

If it isn't I think we should state this on the "suggest a synonym" page as I am seeing too many examples of this.

Comment: Edit tip: `[tag:tag_name]` will give you a tag in the body instead of having to use code mark up.  It also makes it clickable and will take you to the tag.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks but some of these tags are made up for example purposes only.

Comment: Does [tag:java] necessarily mean [tag:java-8] or [tag:java-classes]? No, thus, these aren't synonyms.

Comment: @ForceBru Yeah I am inclined to agree with you. But can you argue the other way round. i.e `java-8` does mean `java` as well.

Comment: @YahyaUddin, true, but for two words to be synonyms, this must work in _both ways_.

Comment: @ForceBru feel free to give your comments as an answer. But year I agree!